# Xamarin Forms: access View of databound ListView item?

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

I have a custom datatemplate for my `ListView`.
The business object (e.g. type of "`Person`") has many properties and *I want to avoid having too many bindings* for every property, also because some would be difficult to set up.

So I would prefer to **set the view's property values** (of e.g. "`PersonCell`") **manually/directly**, just after the `View` has been created and it's `BindingContext`/DataContext has been set to a "Person" instance.

The problem: I don't know how to access those `View` instances.

Is it possible at all to access the `View` created for a data item ? 
And where would I do this ? (In `OnBindingContextChanged` I don't seem to be able to get access to the view associated with the provided data item/BindingContext)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you extract your `DataTemplate` to a Control so that you have:

```
partial class PersonCell : Grid
{
   public PersonCell()
   {
      InitialiseComponent();
   }

   Protected Override OnBindingContextChanged()
   {
      //set up bindings here
   }
}
```

With your View defined in Xaml

And then in your `ListView` use it like so:

```
<ListView>
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
       <custom:PersonCell/>
     </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Where `custom` is an Xaml namespace you define (where `PersonCell` resides)

Comment: And I finally solved the problem by storing the PersonCell instance in my Person object in OnBindingContextChanged, so I can access it later anywhere in my page. Bad style, but it works.